# Should I use past continuous or past tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

I'm not really sure which tense is more accurate when I just want to simply describe where I was working when I was in London one year ago. Should I use past continuous or past tense?

I was working at Pizza hut last year.
I worked at Pizza hut last year.

I would personally use first option but use of past continuous is varied.

Answer (score 2):

The past continuous or past progressive emphasizes the duration of the action. Instead, the past simple shows the past action as a closed process, one that started and finished (in a résumé, for example, you would use the past simple: 2016: I worked at Pizza Hut).

The past continuous is usually used when combined with some other time reference, for example:

- This time last year I **was working** at Pizza Hut.
- I **was working** at Pizza Hut when I got a job offer from McDonald's.

See that in the two examples above the action of working at Pizza Hut is described as something in progress.